# Using Bitset to display 16 bits into four groups of 4 bits in C++

Tags: c++, binary, output, std-bitset

I'm working on a programming assignment and I am using the bitset<> function in C++ to print put the binary representation of an integer by 16 bits. I am having a hard time trying to print the 16 bits into four groups of four bits with a space in between. How can I do that with a bitset function?

```
cout << "0b" << bitset<16>(integer) << "\t";
```

This prints out if the integer was 1

```
0b0000000000000001
```

What i am trying to print out is

```
0b0000 0000 0000 0001
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a filtering stream, but why not keep it simple?

```
auto the_number = std::bitset<16>(1);

std::cout << "0b";
int count = 0;
for(int i=the_number.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    std::cout << std::bitset<16>(255)[i];
    if(++count == 4) {std::cout << " "; count = 0;}
}
```

Comment: Okay except that your solution does not output what the person asking exampled...yours outputs 0b0000 0000 1111 1111 while the person asking apparently wants 0b0000 0000 0000 0001  :)

Comment: I think your comment was not for real, was it? But ok, I edited the example anyway.

Comment: DrSvanHay    not for real at all...except for the sarcasm and the happy face

Answer (score 0):

The `<<`-operator for bitsets does not provide a format specifier that separates the nibbles. You'll have to iterate through the bits on your own and introduce separators "manually":

```
int main() {

    int integer = 24234;
    bitset<16> bits(integer);
    cout << "0b";
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < bits.size(); ++i) {
        if (i && i%4 == 0) { // write a space before starting a new nibble (except before the very first nibble)
            cout << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << bits[bits.size() - i - 1];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay except that your solution does not output what the person asking exampled....Your solution outputs 0b0101 0101 0111 1010   while the person asking apparently wants 0b0000 0000 0000 0001  :)

Comment: @Drt no. This one is not okay, it prints the bits in the wrong order.

Comment: DrSvanHay    ahhhhhhhhhh you are right!!!   Ha ha.  I got so excited to be sarcastic that I missed it!!  :)

Comment: Ah yes.  That is much better.  Guess I missed a golden opportunity to edit.